# htaccess to allow only visits from ip but whitelist a dir and a file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to add a htaccess to allow visits from a specific ip.

The tree goes like this

```
domain
  /abc/
  /def/
```

I want to restrict the folder `/abc/` but whitelist the folder `/def/`

Also, on the `/abc/` there is a specific file called `ghi.php`. Can I allow access to that specific file ?

How can I do this?

This is what i have in /abc/ that redirects everyone who is not into the specified ip. However, I want to allow access to the ghi.php inside that dir.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^125\.17\.119\.16$
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/ [R]
```

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: writing code would be a good start... we don't do that for you. we only (maybe) try help fix what you've attempted.

Comment: @MarcB I have added what I have done so far. Thank you

Comment: @JayBlanchard I have added what I have done so far. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
#Allow access to the file
RewriteRule ^abc/ghi\.php$ - [L]
#forbid the request for /abc/* if ip not=1.2.3.4.5
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^1\.2\.3\.4\.5$
RewriteRule ^abc - [F,L]
```

If you want to redirect the request to homepage, just change the line

```
RewriteRule ^abc - [F,L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^abc http://example.com/ [L,R]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use mod_rewrite for content protection, use the modules that are created for this:

```
# Default: deny all
Order Allow,Deny
# Allow the IP for everything
Allow from 125.17.119.16

# Allow access to this one PHP file
<Files /abc/ghi.php>
    Allow from all
</Files>

# Allow access to everything inside that folder
<FilesMatch "^/def/">
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```